# Does Community Designer Template : Kokua not support PKB？

Tags: knowledge, site.com, community

We are implementing KB in community using Template:Kokua now.

With login, user can access article and category.

And without login, user can only see a web frame only, no category, no article(had message "no articles found"), also search bar can not found any article.

Does these template support access knowledge without login?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I got the answer.

Any impletation for PKB(public knowledge base) are using a package in appExchange

named "[Public Knowledge for Mobile, Web and Facebook](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000059QxXEAU&tab=r)" (now is version 3).

It's using the Visualforce page and some setting. I think there is a gap between

Community Designer and PKB (like Community Force.com Site). So I would use the PKB

in my project.